# Moving Primary AG Replia to new location

Tags: availability-groups, migration, clustering

DBA by accident here so apologies if I'm a little vague!!

My current workplace use a three node SQL 2016 cluster, not virtual. One of the nodes is a primary replica and requires moving to a new data center and I've been asked to look into safe options. I know its a challenge for me and we may hire this out but I'm really keen to at least look into things.

I'm not really sure on the hardware side but is it possible to lift and shift the hardware to a new location and when plugged back in, it will just pick up where it left off in terms of data replication?

There is the option to build new servers at the new DC instead, and my thought was to build an identical server on the same software and add to the AG that way and then remove the old server when all is running OK - is that the better option? I'm assuming we cannot add a new server with newer software ie SQL 2022 to the current cluster?